# Exibir apenas triângulo superior ou inferior de ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2

A função ggpairs do pacote GGally implementa uma versão da pairs para ggplot. O tipo de gráfico exibido no triângulo superior, inferior e na diagonal da matriz pode ser customizado com as opções `upper`, `lower` e `diag`. Assim para, por exemplo, exibir apenas o triângulo superior:

```
library(GGally)

dados <- iris[, 1:4]

plot.mtx <- ggpairs(dados,
  upper = list(continuous = "points"),
  lower = list(continuous = "blank"),
  diag  = list(continuous = "blankDiag")
)

> plot.mtx
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, as linhas e colunas sem gráficos continuam sendo exibidas. Como fazer para que sejam exibidas apenas as linhas/colunas com gráficos?

Answer (score 2):

[Esta solução foi dada por Richard Telford no SO em inglês para o triângulo inferior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656454/9817508), estou expandindo e detalhando a resposta aqui.

A ggpair cria uma lista de *plots* seguindo uma matriz por linhas. No caso de 4 variáveis, temos:

```
> matrix(1:ncol(dados)^2, nrow = ncol(dados), byrow = TRUE)
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
[4,]   13   14   15   16

> length(plot.mtx$plots)
[1] 16

> plot.mtx$nrow; plot.mtx$ncol
[1] 4
[1] 4
```

Assim, para o caso de exibir o triângulo superior, precisamos cortar os *plots* da primeira coluna e da diagonal. No caso do triângulo inferior, da última linha e da diagonal. Entre esses passos, também é necessário atualizar os números de linhas e colunas (armazenados em elementos próprios dentro da lista do ggpairs), bem como os rótulos:

```
ggpairs_upper <- function(g) {
  g$plots <- g$plots[-seq(length(g$plots)-g$nrow+1, length(g$plots))]
  g$yAxisLabels <- g$yAxisLabels[-g$nrow]
  g$nrow <- g$nrow -1
  g$plots <- g$plots[-seq(1, g$nrow*g$ncol, by = g$ncol+1)]
  g$xAxisLabels <- g$xAxisLabels[-1]
  g$ncol <- g$ncol - 1
  g
}

ggpairs_lower <- function(g) {
  g$plots <- g$plots[-(1:g$nrow)]
  g$yAxisLabels <- g$yAxisLabels[-1]
  g$nrow <- g$nrow -1
  g$plots <- g$plots[-(seq(g$ncol, length(g$plots), by = g$ncol))]
  g$xAxisLabels <- g$xAxisLabels[-g$ncol]
  g$ncol <- g$ncol - 1
  g
}

> ggpairs_upper(plot.mtx)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]